# how to send transactional emails using constant contact in php

Tags: php, email, constantcontact

Present  I am using Sendgrid for sending transnational emails after donating/ registering the user. and Constant Contact for sending news letters to subscribed users in my website.

I want to use only one server for both.

Is there any possibility to send transnational emails using Constant Contact.
I have already searched in developer.constantcontact website. But there is no exact solution. In that they given api for adding emails to list in campaign. and creating campaign and sending email to all users in that list.

Is there any possibility to send email notification to registered/donated user immedieately without creating Campaign.

Please hemp me.

Answer (score 0):

No.
You'll need to use something like [Mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com/) by MailChimp for transactional emails.  Maybe CC will add support at some point, but I wouldn't count on it.